# $X$ and $Y$ are independent Poisson distributed values with means $θ$ and $2θ$. Consider the combined estimator $\gamma = k_1\cdot X + k_2\cdot Y$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

$X$ and $Y$ are independent Poisson distributed values, means are $θ$ and $2θ$.

Consider the combined estimator $$\gamma = k_1\cdot X + k_2\cdot Y$$ where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are arbitrary constants.

(a) Find the condition on $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $\gamma$ is an unbiased estimator.

To solve this I let $\theta = E[k_1X + k_2Y] = k_1E[X] + k_2E[Y]$

$\theta = k_1\theta + 2k_2\theta$, $k_1 + 2k_2 = 1$

However I'm stuck when it comes to the next 2 parts:

(b) For $\gamma$ unbiased, show that the variance of the estimator is minimized by taking
$k_1 = 1/3$ and $k_2 = 1/3$.

(c) Given observations x and y find the maximum likelihood estimate of θ. and
hence show that $\gamma$ is also the maximum likelihood estimator.

I'm not sure where to even start for part (b) and part (c). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Didn't find those answers when searching! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: If you want the right direction for question b), the first step is too calculate the variance of the estimator as function of $k_1$ and $k_2$